# How to get Current User's Email address and password in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I'm wondering is there any solution to get current users email and password from outlook with C# ? I need those information to send e-mail from desktop app for log.

Comment: There is no way to get a users password, allowing that would be a huge security hole in any system.

Comment: only what you can - open send message diaalog for current user.

Comment: Outlook doesn't store that data, you need to get it from Active Directory. And as @DavidG said, you can't get the password, just the email

Comment: Okay I get it. Well how can I send email from current outlook account via my app ? Let's say I got the account's e-mail address from outlook. I mean I need to send e-mail from current user's e- mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have tagged ASP-Classic, I guess you are trying implement this in classic ASP. I would suggest you to create a new aspx page or a handler (ashx) in .Net. Then you can implement your email functionality in that class using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`.
Refer- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb644320.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 and [Sending Email through Outlook 2010 via C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911230/sending-email-through-outlook-2010-via-c-sharp)
Please note- You need to use an existing Windows account which can send and receive mails.

Comment: Thanks, second url is the solution for me. Also I found this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff462091.aspx . It might help someone.

Comment: What on earth does this answer have to do with classic ASP? How does "create a new aspx page" qualify as classic ASP?

Comment: @Martha Based on my experience, I found it was easier to create a handler or an aspx page to handle some of the common .Net related stuffs like this. It gave me more control. Anyway, it is developers choice. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh: I still don't get it. Classic ASP and dot-net are mutually exclusive. If you have to deal with "common .Net related stuff", then you can't possibly be using classic ASP. At least in *my* universe.

Comment: @Martha I am not pointing the differences between Classic ASP and .Net. People are well aware of that. I have only answered the question with suggestion which the user has accepted.