# C# WPF - Launch Default Mail Application with HTML body

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I would like to do the exact same thing mailto: does, but I want HTML in the body.  Is there any way to do this?

It doesn't have to use mailto: as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body) states.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without resorting to specific command line arguments for different clients.

Comment: If you have Outlook installed, you could use the Outlook object model to [send HTML mails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911230/sending-email-through-outlook-2010-via-c-sharp). Another option would be to use an external tool like [blat](http://blat.sourceforge.net)

Comment: Not all my clients have outlook installed.  Blat has no UI correct?  It just sends it.