How do you create and display email templates in VB.Net using Microsoft Office Interop
I have been trying to fill out a basic email template for company software in VB.Net using Microsoft Office Interop. I have found several examples of how to do it, but for some reason, it is not working. I run the code and nothing(apparently) happens. I don't get any error messages. Its just that nothing happens. The code executes, the screen does not change, and Task Manager shows no changes. I don't know if its creating the message and simply hiding it, or what is going wrong. What I am trying to do is to create an email that is already half written for the user to complete and then send manually.
Thanks.
'''
    Dim appl As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application
    appl = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application

    Dim omsg As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem
    omsg = appl.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
    omsg.Recipients.Add("test123@test.com")
    omsg.Subject = "Can you let me know if you received this email"
    omsg.Body = "This is the body of the email"
    omsg.Display()

'''

give tis a try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65412215/how-to-send-emails-in-vb-net-using-the-outlook-library

As you step though your code, do you see outlook.exe process in Task Manager after instantiating appl?

I don't know why. But after restarting my computer this morning. The code runs fine. The blank email is created and pops up right when it is supposed to.
